# Bitcoin URI "r=" param. How it works?

Tags: url, request, uri, bitcoin, bitcoind

Example:

```
bitcoin:?r=https://bitpay.com/i/WEZPwt4tjjN9UXZrxSnTKu
```

It not gone work now, because bitpay payment is available only 15 minutes. But if you have an active payment it opens your Bitcoin app (f.e. Bitcoin core) and make your forms filled.

[image]

**How to do smartlink like this?** If im using simply URI I can put `bitcoin:1ADDRESS?amount=1` etc., but I want to do it like a Bitpay.

Answer (score 0):

The argument `r=` is defined in [BIP-72](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0072.mediawiki) and means that more details must be obtained through the link

Bitpay uses [Bitcoin Payment Protocol](https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/payment-protocol) defined in [BIP 70 Protocol](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0070.mediawiki)

But if you open the link in a browser, it will show bitpay invoice page. In this case you need to pass a HTTP header to get the real payment request:

`wget --header="Accept: application/bitcoin-paymentrequest" https://bitpay.com/i/WEZPwt4tjjN9UXZrxSnTKu`

It will return a [protocol buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), is what your application should do.